# How to create a project template that installs latest NuGet dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I want to create a template that installs the latest version of a NuGet package and all of its dependencies. Most common solution using `NuGet.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard` installs only specified package version and doesn't resolve any dependencies. Basically I want to run `Install-Package example` when a project using my template is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found 2 ways to do that. New .csproj standard supports `PackageReference` directives for including NuGet packages and supports version wildcards and prefers highest version available. But it is currently too buggy so I ended up implementing my own `IWizard` that works like NuGet's default wizard but installs latest packages and dependencies:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using EnvDTE;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard;
using NuGet.VisualStudio;
using Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;

namespace Example
{
    public class NuGetTemplateWizard : IWizard
    {
        List<string> _packages;

        public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
        {
            if (customParams.Length > 0) {
                var vstemplate = XDocument.Load((string)customParams[0]);
                _packages = vstemplate.Root
                    .ElementsNoNamespace("WizardData")
                    .ElementsNoNamespace("packages")
                    .ElementsNoNamespace("package")
                    .Select(pkg => pkg.Attribute("id").Value)
                    .ToList();
            }
        }

        public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
        {
            Task.Run(delegate {
                var componentModel = (IComponentModel)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel));
                var _installer = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstaller2>();

                foreach (var package in _packages) {
                    _installer.InstallLatestPackage(null, project, package, false, false);
                }
            });
        }

        public bool ShouldAddProjectItem(string filePath) { return true; }
        public void BeforeOpeningFile(ProjectItem projectItem) { }
        public void ProjectItemFinishedGenerating(ProjectItem projectItem) { }
        public void RunFinished() { }
    }
}
```

and in .vstemplate:

```
  <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>Example, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7a55be3860fb01d1</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>Example.NuGetTemplateWizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
  <WizardData>
    <packages>
      <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" />
    </packages>
  </WizardData>
```

Also I'm not sure whether it is safe to install packages in background via `Task.Run` but it feels more responsive this way and all async nuget methods are internal (not available) anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> How to create a project template that installs latest NuGet dependencies?

Obviously, your requirement is very clear. But we do not recommend you doing that. Because update the packages will break the template.

What we know is that preinstalled packages work using [template wizards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms185301.aspx). A special wizard gets invoked when the template gets instantiated. The wizard loads the list of packages that need to be installed and passes that information to the appropriate NuGet APIs.

Besides, both the `id` and `version` attributes are required in the wizard, which used to specify version of a package will be installed even if a newer version is available. **This prevents package updates from breaking the template, leaving the choice to update the package to the developer using the template.**

what's more, update the package by the developer is a very simple matter. And developers could update some packages according to their requirement, no need update all packages.

Comment: How do you imagine including the latest jQuery in an empty project for example to break a template? And if by some miracle it does it's easier to update the template once than updating jQuery for every new release and template instance. I think template developer should decide whether he wants latest versions or not, it depends on a template. By the way new .csproj files allow this in a very flexible way via `PackageReference` but it is currently too buggy.